# need to calculate the time difference but if the closing time in empty return 0

Tags: if-statement, sharepoint, calculation

wanted to calculate the time deferent between two time stamp and result in Min but if the closing time still not there or empty return 0

i used this for the calculation:
=INT(([Timestamp closed case]-[Timestamp open case])*1440)&" Min"

and its working fine but if the closing time is missing it will give a number (-65207335 Min)

so im trying to use the below and it show me an error in the formula.

=ISBLANK([Timestamp closed case]), 0 ,(INT(([Timestamp closed case]-[Timestamp open case])*1440)&" Min" )

Note: Timestamp closed case is formatted as date/time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this calculated foluma:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Timestamp closed case]),0&"Min",(INT(([Timestamp closed case]-[Timestamp open case])*1440)&" Min")
```

[image]

Comment: that is nice it solved the issue, but i may remove the "MIN" as i will use this data to calculate the total time. thanks.